# How to read restful response on client side in java for post

Tags: java, web-services, post, restful-architecture

I have returning response to client as

```
return Response.status(200).entity("Data was succesfully loaded into database").build();
```

I have to read this on client my client code

```
 URL url=new URL(urlString);
       // URLConnection connection=url.openConnection();
        //connection.setDoOutput(true);
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
        httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                "application/json");
```

how to read these type of responses on client side

Answer (score 0):

Once you have HttpURLConnection you can send data to the server (if this is needed, but looks like as it is, because you have POST request):

```
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpCon.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(yourData);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

Then you can check for response code (for e.g. if it is 200):

```
int responseCode = httpCon.getResponseCode();
```

And read data from response:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream()));
String line;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```

If you want to parse JSON you can use [org.json](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java) or [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: Isn`t this auto generated code from The advanced rest client opensource software? I think we should give due to credit to those developers as well

Comment: I don't know. Small piece of code, well known pattern. I didn't read that book.